# How can I limit the participant role choice?

Tags: civievent, registration, roles

I've been using CiviCRM for a few years now, mostly for basic functions (small NPO organizing events).

I'm trying to use a function that seems common to me but I feel that I'm missing something because I can't find any information about it.

I've tried almost everything within the interface. I have no knowledge or experience in coding script or stuff like this. But I can try following instructions.

Here is my case:

Our NPO set up LARP events for everybody.
-Anyone can register and choose a participant role.
-We mostly have these possibilities: Player, NPC, Volunteers, Artist, Organizers.
-Every participant might have custom field related to his (participant) role
-We'd like to let people choose their role properly instead of batch changing it based on the selected price in the set.

BUT:
As we also organize other types of event like conferences, where participant roles are not the same.

We would to like to be able to allow registering participants to select a role within a limited list which does not include every role set in CiviEvent
(How) can we do this?

PS I can give you any details you might find useful.

Comment: Hi, is this for paid events or free? are you on drupal/joomla or wordpress? if the first, webform can help you

Comment: This is a paid event on wordpress :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this feature will be released one day but I would find it pretty useful.
You could select a role list base on an event type or template.

However [this extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/event-registration-based-participant-roles) just came out a few days after my question, and it could help if anyone is in the same situation.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the only way at this time to do this at this time without using (Drupal) Webform is to write custom code.

For custom code, there are a wide variety of approaches - you can write an extension that uses [hook_civicrm_buildForm](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_buildForm) (or hook_civicrm_alterContent or hook_civicrm_alterTemplateFile, but IMO these are less elegant).  Or you can put a .extra.tpl file in your template override folder with a jQuery snippet to hide roles on certain events.